# AccountController GetExternalLogin method

Tags: security, claims-based-identity, owin, asp.net-web-api2, katana

Could anyone please explain the GetExternalLogin method to me. I want to redirect from this method to another location, but whenever I do that access token from external provider disappears from url. Where do access token details leave in this method after successful signing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dominick explains this in his blog post:

http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/26/dissecting-the-web-api-individual-accounts-templatepart-3-external-accounts/

Comment: Thanks, that post was very useful, but still does not resolve my problem. I left a comment hoping for an explanation on how to implement an additional step (external from Web API) after GetExternalLogin method is executed and before RegisterExternal methods will be called.